# Delete axios method returns empty data

Tags: javascript, axios, graphql, apollo-server

I have successfully implemented a really simple example to use graphql and apollo-server and json-server. But the delete method returns empty data. I console.log(res.data) and is empty. Any help?

Resolver mutation methods:

```
type Mutation {
    addCustomer(name: String!, email: String!, age: Int!): Customer!
    editCustomer(id: ID!, name: String!, email: String!, age: Int!): Customer!
    deleteCustomer(id: ID!): Customer!
  }
```

The typeDef of deleted customer:

```
deleteCustomer: async (_, { id }) => {
    const res = await axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/customers/" + id);
    return res.data;
},
```

The code is here, in case the provided code is not enough: https://github.com/motapinto/learn-graphql-apollo-server

Comment: I don't see what a HTTP `DELETE` request has to do with GraphQL?

Comment: @Bergi nothing but it was just to give context. The customer with id 1 is deleted if I try but the data that is return is empty. Shouldn't it return the whole object (the customer) that it's deleted?

Comment: Oh, I see now that this is the resolver implementation of your `deleteCustomer` mutation. And the json-server apparently doesn't return the deleted object - if you want that, you'd have to `GET` it before deleting it.

Answer (score -1):

Just ran your code there. It looks like if you delete it it returns null or an empty object. In this case I believe you should return the id, and check your `res` variable, to make sure there is no errors and return that with the id.

Something like the code below. But, there could be a better way.

```
    deleteCustomer: async (_, { id }) => {
        const res = await axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/customers/" + id);
        if (res.status !== 200) return { success: false};

        return { success: true, id}; 
};
```

Comment: Yes thank you that is a possibility yes, but I wanted to get the whole object. It seems that with json-server I have to get the customer first and only after delete it